# Java MYSQL Query , get 2 variables from different tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Got a question, how can i get 2 different variables from different tables using mysql? Is it possible to make it work from 1 query using prepared statement? I'm new at mysql database programming with java, so that's my problem.

I'm trying to get:

```
user_key from user table
project_key from project table
```

and yes, I know, table names should be in non singular form.

I'm trying :

```
String project_key = null;
String user_key = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql:" + Config.getPortDB() +  "/" + Config.getDatabase() + "?"
            + "user=" + Config.getUsername() + "&password=" + Config.getPassword());

String query ="SELECT user_key,project_key FROM user, project WHERE user_key = ? AND project_key = ?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);

for(int i = 0; i < auths.size() ; i++ ) {
    preparedStatement.setString(i+1, auths.get(i));
}

ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {  
    project_key = rs.getString("project_key");
    user_key = rs.getString("user_key");
}

System.out.println(project_key); // null
System.out.println(user_key); // null
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what you are doing should work, although better to use a `JOIN` - what is going wrong with your code?

Comment: Getting "null" exception when i try to get values from ResultSet

Comment: well you need to show that code then

Comment: Updated , added full code.

Comment: run your code in a sql client and see they output - probably not what you are wanting

Comment: Also if you debug, it you can see if `while` is being entered into

Comment: what is `auths` ?

Comment: @YCF_L auths array which has project_key and user_key from config json file. These to have to be same as in database to let user use the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT u.user_key,
       p.project_key 
FROM (select user_key from user WHERE user_key = ?) u, 
     (select project_key from project WHERE project_key = ?) p
```

If the tow tables has no relation at all you still can get the 2 values using subqueries

Comment: Thanks, but still got these null exceptions.. :?

Comment: Looks like the query returns nothing.Check which parameters are sent to the query and check the separate queries return some rows (e.g. from Workbench call)

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL, your query worked.

Thanks all who was replying, having really bad morning, can't wake up normally, forgot to parse strings from Config file when i was changing names of variables..

Answer (score 0):

This is your current query:

```
SELECT user_key,project_key 
FROM user, project 
WHERE user_key = ? 
  AND project_key = ?
```

To get results from 2 tables use **JOIN**, like this:

```
SELECT u.user_key, p.project_key 
FROM user u
JOIN  project p ON p.userId = u.id
WHERE u.user_key = ? 
  AND p.project_key = ?
```

Comment: How do you know he has userId and id columns in tables (ON p.userId = u.id)

Comment: @Ervinas34 u - short name for User, p - for project. You can see in FROM and JOIN statements.

Comment: @Chetanchadha I don't. It's just example.

Comment: @Max Thanks, i'll try something by the example.

Comment: @Max still can't figure it out how it works. JOIN ON i meant.

Comment: @Ervinas34 well, google it. Here you can read about it: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @Max do i really need to use JOIN? Because i don't want to compare or get same values that are IN different TWO tables. In my program i want to check if there are matches found in Database from java code.

As you see, got "auths" array, i'm checking if there are any matches in database.

So maybe it was missundertood? Because i don't actually see a reason to use join, i don't want to compare two different tables, i just need to get 2 values from 2 different tables.

Comment: Ok. Check out @StanislavL answer then.